# What's the meaning about this square frame around the "null" in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm newbie in eclipse, what's this square frame around the "null" means.

[image: what's the meaning about the square frame around the "null"]

Comment: looks like highlighting occurrences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like an editing box. Sometimes when you do things like inserting code from a template or letting Eclipse add unimplemented abstract methods it will put these edit boxes around the default values that you're likely to change. If you click on it and hit enter it should go away.

Comment: Simply pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> should remove it as well.

Comment: You can also put your text cursor on any class / function / variable name, press alt + shift + r and you can replace the variable name without breaking references

Comment: @gerrytan Yup, alt + shift + r does the rename globally. You can also use ctrl + 2, r to rename only in the current file.